# How can i make a URL-shortcut?

Tags: app-shortcuts

I tried creating a [`.desktop`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) file in `/usr/share/applications`, but it doesn't work.
I need shortcut for URL-address with own icon in Dock-panel like in Windows OS.

Comment: For what browser?

Comment: the answer works: also, you don't need to add the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`, nor in `~/.local/share/applications` unless you need it to be seen in Applications Slingshot launcher. You can put it in something like `~/My_launchers` and drag & drop it on Plank area. --- Anyway, to create a desktop launcher in `usr/share/applications` you need `sudo` - like `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/my_url.desktop`

Comment: Firefox or Midori.

Comment: but read last post - your advice didn't help me or i just so newbie.

Answer (score 3):

This will probably do:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=WebsiteName
GenericName=websitename
Exec=xdg-open http://www.yourwebsite.com
Terminal=false
Icon=
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;X-Developer;
```

xdg-open will open the default browser with the argument http://www.yourwebsite.com.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=LinkName
Type=Link
URL=http://site.com
Icon=text-html
```

Browser Midori or Firefox.

It  doesn't work

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=WebsiteName
GenericName=websitename
Exec=xdg-open http://www.yourwebsite.com
Terminal=false
Icon=
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;X-Developer;
```

[image]

> Slingshot launcher.

I didn't find in Apps menu this software.

> You can put it in something like ~/My_launchers

How can i do it? Menu by right mouse doesn't work in Applications menu.

> you need sudo - like sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/my_url.desktop

sudo gedit - command not found.

Why i can't create by root app "files" from menu Applications empty file in  /usr/share/applications/? I made file like that, but it doesn't work.